# Calcular total de dias trabalhados em um certo mês

Tags: php, mysql

Eu estou com um problema na criação de um sistema em PHP/MySQL. Eu tenho um formulário em que preciso inserir:

- Nome do Funcionário
- Data de entada no plantão
- Data de Saída

Geralmente acontece algo como no exemplo: o funcionário entra no dia 29/04/2014 e sai dia 03/05/2014. Preciso setar 2 dias trabalhados para abril, e 3 dias trabalhados para maio. Como posso resolver esse problema? E não sei qual a melhor forma de criar as tabelas no banco. Alguém poderia dar uma luz?

Comment: Olá, tenta fazer algo como isto: `$dia2 = date('d')+2;
if($dia2 !== date('d')){
 //Hoje nao é o dia de saída insere a data actual
 //insert into x where xxx values date('d/M/Y');
 } else {
  //insert into x where xxx values date
  }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Converta as datas para timestamp PHP. Ex:

```
$entrada = mktime(0,0,0,4,29,2014); //29/04/2014
$saida = mktime(0,0,0,5,3,2014); // 03/05/2014
```

2) Avalie se há diferença nos meses. Se houver diferença você deverá fazer dois cálculos, um pra cada mês. Se não houver você só precisa subtrair as datas.

```
$mesEntrada = date('n', $entrada);
$mesSaida = date('n', $saida );

if ($mesEntrada != $mesSaida)
{
    $diasTrabalhadosMesEntrada = (date("t", $entrada)-date("j",$entrada))+1; // Subtrai o total de dias do mes pelo dia de entrada.
    $diasTrabalhadosMesSaida = date('j', $saida ); // A quantidade de dias trabalhados é igual ao dia de saída.

    // Inserir no BD...
}
else
{
   // Apenas 1 mes (mesEntrada igual a mesSaida);
   $diasTrabalhados = date("j",$saida)-date("j",$entrada);

   // Inserir no BD...
}
```

Com relação ao BD, você pode criar uma tabela que armazena em colunas distintas o mês, o ano e a quantidade de dias trabalhados (colunas funcionario, mes, ano e dias_trabalhados). Aconselho criar também uma tabela de historico que armazena todas entradas e saídas do funcionário (colunas funcionario, entrada e saida).

Sugiro consultar http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.date.php para um melhor entendimento.

Não testei o código, é apenas um direcionamento.

Comment: Porque converter elas para timestamp?

Comment: Pra facilitar as operações com data.

Comment: @ArivanBastos o $diasTrabalhadosMesEntrada não ta dando certo, ele só me retorna 0, mesmo quando o funcionário trabalha. =/ //não estranhem eu respondendo com dois perfis, é que no meu trabalho não dá pra logar com o facebook.

Comment: @JoãoNeto, havia um erro no código. Corrigi. Mas como falei é apenas um direcionamento, busque depurar e entender a lógica, assim você aprende +! :-)

Comment: Valeu Arivan, tinha decidido que iria fazer isso, e não ia pedir ajuda aqui. Mas to fazendo sistema pra um juiz, então to com pressa kkkkk. Valeu.

Answer (score 1):

Que tal isso:

**Tabela funcionários:**

- id
- nome

**Tabela plantões:**

- id
- funcionario_id
- entrada
- saida

E aí tu consegue os dias trabalhados fazendo `saida - entrada`. Se essa informação não é para ser mudada mais tarde, tu pode até criar uma coluna para ela na tebela `plantões`.

Comment: Hmmm, exatamente isso. Mas tem um outro problema, eu preciso que fique registrado, que o funcionário trabalhou x dias no mês y. Dessa maneira só mostraria o total né? Como faria para adicionar os meses? Para que eu pudesse exibir por mês?

Comment: @JoãoNeto Acho que nesse caso tu precisaria de uma tabela `dias_trabalhados`ou `histórico_plantão`. Os registros seriam inseridos nela via aplicação assim que o usuário enviar o formulário. Via PHP tu teria que fazer este algoritmo. Por exemplo, se ele entrar 05/05 e sair 10/05 só vai entrar um registro para o mês 05 com 5 dias. Mas se entrar 25/05 e sair 05/06 aí são inseridos 2 registros, um para o mês 05 (6 dias) e outro para o 06 (5 dias). Aí tu pode somar os plantões daquele mês.

Comment: @JoãoNeto Tu pode fazer isto numa tabela separada da `plantões` e pode resolver fazer apenas esta. Depende da tua necessidade.

Comment: foi desse mesmo jeito que pensei, farei assim. Assim que chegar no trabalho começarei a fazer. Creio que essa solução vai me atender bem. Obrigado pelo apoio ai!

Comment: @JoãoNeto Fico feliz em poder ajudar. =)