# Como definir as tabelas do banco de dados?

Tags: php, mysql, tabela-banco-de-dados

Preciso computar X horas trabalhadas para um funcionário X no mês X. Por exemplo, João trabalhou 20 dias em janeiro, 12 em fevereiro, e assim por diante. To perdido em relação a tabela, crio uma tabela só para datas? Ou crio colunas dentro da tabela do funcionário com: `jan`, `fev`, `mar`. Que no caso acho que não é o certo a se fazer.

Comment: Como estes dados serão imputados ? O melhor modelo seria na minha opinião um que se registre : Funcionário data e horade inicio, data e hora final e as horas trabalhadas seriam calculadas.

Comment: Por meio de um formulário. Se quiser dar uma olhada no problema todo: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15837/calcular-total-de-dias-trabalhados-em-um-certo-mes / é outra conta minha, no trabalho não dá pra logar com facebook.

Comment: É necessário gravar as horas do dia, como se fosse um relógio de ponto ou só o número de dias no mês?

Comment: Serão por meio de um formulário onde informo nome, data entrada, data de saída. A forma como vai ser manipulado o dado já sei. Só preciso agora definir a inserção dos dias no banco.

Comment: Apenas o número de dias felipe.

Comment: E é preciso saber quais foram esses dias?

Comment: Sim filipe, para depois comparar com os dias que são feriados.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que esta solução vai te ajudar:

```
Tabela FUNCIONARIOS =>

functionario_id  nome
1                João
2                André


Tabela HORAS_TRABALHADAS = >

funcionario_id  mes  horas
1               10   20
2               10   12
1               11   5
```

Se você quiser aumentar o nível de precisão do relatório, vale a pena colocar cada data por linha - manter todas as horas de um mês em uma mesma linha vai tornar mais complicado recalcular algum dia que tenha sido registrado errado na folha de ponto.

```
Tabela HORAS_TRABALHADAS = >

funcionario_id  data        horas
1               02/01/2014  8
2               02/01/2014  8
1               02/01/2014  5
```

Assim, se você quiser selecionar a linha do João no dia 02/01, execute

```
SELECT * FROM HORAS_TRABALHADAS WHERE funcionario_id = 1 AND data = 02/01/2014
```

Answer (score 1):

**Se você apenas quer contabilizar o número de dias**, basta criar um campo.
Na hora de gerar relatórios, evita adicionar mais uma tabela a sua query.
Dentro desse campo grave os dados da seguinte forma:

```
12,15,13,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

Cada posição representa um mês, Janeiro, Fevereiro, etc...
Para acrescentar +1 dia ao respectivo mês, antes de gravar, é preciso converter os dados em array utilizando a função [explode](http://www.php.net/explode):

```
$aDias = explode(",",string_com_os_dias);
```

Na string que usamos como exemplo, temos até o mês de Abril preenchido.
Um exemplo para adicionar mais um dia ao mês de Abril.

```
$aDias[3] += 1; //passa a 6
```

Antes de gravar os dados, volte a converter o array em string. Para isso utilize a função [implode](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.implode.php):

```
$sDias = implode(",",$aDias);
```

Isso é um exemplo caso seja necessário apenas gravar os número de dias.
**Se você quer gravar a data em que o trabalho foi realizado,** é preciso criar uma tabela a parte.
Crie uma nova tabela, por exemplo "TB_HORAS" com os campos:

- ID - int //autocomplete
- ID_FUNCIONARIO - int //id do respectivo funcionário correspondente a tabela de funcionários
- DATA - date //data em que o trabalho foi realizado
- HORAS - int //número de horas

Para fazer a busca por mês e contabilizar todos os dias, por exemplo, mês de maio para o funcionário com ID=5:

```
SELECT SUM(HORAS) FROM TB_HORAS WHERE ID_FUNCIONARIO = 5 AND DATA between '2014-05-01' AND '2014-05-31'
```

Answer (score 1):

Grave os registros por dia. Isso lhe dará mais opções para melhorias em seu sistema no futuro e permitirá ter histórico dos anos.

**1) Crie uma tabela para funcionarios e outra para registro diário de horas trabalhadas:**

```
funcionario
--------------
id    nome
1     João
2     José
3     Maria

horas_trabalhadas
--------------
id    funcionario_id   data           horas
1     1                2014-05-02     8
2     1                2014-05-03     6
3     2                2014-05-02     7
```

**2) Consulte as horas trabalhadas por cada funcionário em um mês (no exemplo abaixo maio de 2014):**

```
SELECT f.id. f.nome, sum(ht.horas) 
FROM funcionario AS f
JOIN horas_trabalhadas AS ht
     ON f.id = ht.funcionario_id
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(ht.data, "%Y") = 2014 AND DATE_FORMAT(ht.data, "%m") = 5
GROUP by f.id, DATE_FORMAT(ht.data, "%Y-%m")
ORDER BY f.nome;
```

Se quiser de um usuário específico basta acrescentar a condição "f.id = {ID DO FUNCIONARIO}" à consulta.

Answer (score 0):

Pensei um pouco e acho que o que você pode fazer é o seguinte:

- Crie os campos NOME, DIAS_TRABALHADOS, MES (se necessário crie ANO)

Ai você vai inserindo na tabela o nome do cara, quantos dias ele trabalhou e em qual mês ele trabalhou. Assim evita de ficar passando muitos dados no INSERT. E te ajudaria no SELECT, pois você só teria que passar um WHERE = mes que vc deseja consultar.